# Using Middleware in node.js and MVC Routes

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I'm having problems deploying a middleware in the routes of my application, basically, its structure is as shown in the following screenshots.

My middleware:

[image]

My Controller:

[image]

My routes.js

[image]

However, when I try to add the middleware to my route there is an error in the application, I am adding the middleware as follows:
[image]

The error returned when starting the application is: ***Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Object]***

My application doesn't have the (req, res) right there after the route declaration, if so, I would just add the middleware first, however, see that my application calls the list method inside the Class Unit directly in the route declaration. How do I increment Middleware there?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed exporting middleware function.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Great!! Works, thanks..